# My Grails app issues http get requests for the same images (a js driven clock) repeatedly. What do I need to do so it doesn't do that?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a Grails app (2.0 RC1) that uses a clock that is made up of images to display the time including seconds. The clock is a simple JavaScript function that gets the time and then updates the image source to show the correct image. The whole app and the clock in it are working just fine.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that each time the clock updates (i.e. once every second) the image source an http get request is sent to the server instead of using the cached images.

The images are precached when the page loads into Image() objects. The function then calculates the time and updates the image like this:

```
document.getElementById('hour1').src = eval('window.' + 'num' + hour1 + '.src')
```

where "num" + hour1 is the name of the Image() object to be displayed. The element in the gsp is an img tag.

I spent hours searching for an answer but to no avail... Do I have to use the "cached resources" plugin to get any caching? If so, could someone tell me how to use that in this case? I played around with that but haven't been able to get that to work yet...

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `eval()` like that.  Replace your `eval()` with this:

```
window["num" + hour1].src
```

Second, your browser will send the GET request and the server should respond with a 304 - Not Modified, which will then cause the browser to use the cached image.  Is your browser serving the image for each request, or is it sending a 304 status code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! From what I can see in Firebug the response is a 302 (sorry, not totally sure if I'm using that right). Funny thing is that the same javascript in a non-grails app doesn't send the constant requests. -- Actually, it does, just not as frequently. Sorry, I really don't know what I'm talking about here... is there any way to prevent all those requests going to the server? that's really what I'm trying to accomplish. (Thanks for the tip on the use of eval() btw.)

Comment: 302 is a redirect status. Perhaps if you change to use the url you are redirected to directly, that would solve your issue. I'm not very familiar with Grails... could it be modifying the URLs?

Comment: Watching for that some more, most responses actually are 200 OK responses and only some are 302 responses. So it seems it's actually serving the images each time. From what I found so far on Grails and caching it understand that it's not doing it out of the box. Looks like I need to do some more reading on this so I actually understand what's going on and check out the "cached resources" plugin some more.